# redirect x.com to y.com

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I did a redirect in the httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName y.com *.y.com
    Redirect permanent / http://x.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted, but the redirect does not work.  The ip address for both domains are the same.

All help appreciated

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) directive is incorrect. Add `*.y.com` with [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) instead.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.y.com
    Redirect permanent / http://x.com/
</VirtualHost> so this would be the correct format?

Comment: No. Read the linked documentation about `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`. You cannot use wildcards with `ServerName`.

Answer (score 1):

to make it clearer what joschi meant:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName y.com
    ServerAlias *.y.com
    Redirect permanent / http://x.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: . It's not working, what could be the possibilities?

Comment: anything in the error logs?